# FILTER_VALIDATE_INT return false always

Tags: php, xampp, filter-var

I am trying to validate integer by using `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`. it is working fine on ubuntu server but return false on my local win 10 xampp system.

here is the code

case 1:

```
$d = "sdaf";
var_dump(filter_var($d, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
```

OP : bool(false)

case 2 :

```
$d = "9876543210";
var_dump(filter_var($d, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
```

OP : bool(false)

case 3 :

```
var_dump(filter_var(9876543210, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
```

OP : bool(false)

On server:

```
var_dump(filter_var(9876543210, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
```

OP : int(9876543210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running a 32 bit Windows, or a 32bit PHP on a 64bit windows, and a 64bit Server?

I think you probably are. If you run this you will get the correct results. Your numbers were greater than the PHP_INT_MAX for a 32bit system

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;

$d = "sdaf";
var_dump(filter_var($d, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));  

$d = PHP_INT_MAX;
var_dump(filter_var($d, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));

var_dump(filter_var(PHP_INT_MAX, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
```

RESULTS:

```
2147483647

bool(false)

int(2147483647)

int(2147483647)
```

Comment: I am getting int(2147483647). I am running win 64 bit

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean

Comment: On server when I run `$d = PHP_INT_MAX;
var_dump(filter_var($d, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));` I get `int(9223372036854775807)` and On local system I get `int(2147483647)`

Comment: RIght, So your Windows box is 32bit OS or you are using a 32bit PHP. All versions of PHP on Windows were 32bit for integers until PHP7.0.0

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: You will have to use a 64bit PHP7 on a 64bit Windows if you want 64 bit integers on Windows

Comment: Do you actually expect to be using integers > 2 billion in your real system?

Comment: When I search on `https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html`. There is only 32 bit xampp available.

Comment: Are you running a 64bit Windows?

Comment: Yea I cannot see a way to download a 64bit version of XAMPP. You might want to try WAMPServer that has 32 and 64bit versions, but still you will need to use PHP7> What version of PHP is your server running

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm pretty sure I'm running a 64-bit version of XAMPP on one of my Windows machine and the same on a \*NIX machine. Edit: My bad; see below comment.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're right; 64 bit XAMPP is not available for Windows; only for \*NIX and MAC OSX https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- _Your input is alway welcome my friend_ They must be working on a 64bit release as PHP7 is now true 64 bit compliant and has been for quite a while now. Seems odd that they are so far behind the curve

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Cheers my friend*. Yeah, you figure that they would and won't have a choice if they want people to use it; one has to *"Keep up with the Jones'"* as it were.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can have 32 bits and 64 bits integers.
The maximum 32 bits integer you can have, it `2147483647`, which is less then yours `9876543210`.

If you have a number that is larger then this, it is converted to a float, so the int validation fails.

If you don't want this, you need to have a 64 bits version of PHP.
AND if you have windows, this needs to be PHP 7 or higher.
Why? 64 bits versions of PHP 5.* have a bug that integers are always 32 bits.

More info: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Hi, its not a bug, it just took the developer some time to work out how to implement 64bit integers for windows in the ported unix code for PHP